# c# wpf - Right-Click to change SelectedDate and show ContextMenu

Tags: c#, wpf, calendar, contextmenu, right-click

I want to implement rightclick event in RadCalendar to change the SelectedDates and also showing the ContextMenu at the same time. I'm using this code :

### XAML

```
<telerik:RadCalendar Name="radCalendar"
                     Canvas.Left="80"
                     Canvas.Top="200"
                     Height="320"
                     Width="400"
                     SelectedDate="{Binding CurrentDate, ElementName=radScheduleView, Mode=TwoWay}"
                     SelectionMode="Single"
                     DisplayDate="{Binding DisplayDate, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <telerik:RadContextMenu.ContextMenu>
        <telerik:RadContextMenu Opened="RadContextMenu_Opened">
            <telerik:RadMenuItem x:Name="expandOverview"
                                 Header="Expand Overview"
                                 Click="expandOverview_Click" />
            <telerik:RadMenuItem x:Name="showLayouts"
                                 Header="Show Layouts"
                                 Click="showLayouts_Click" />
        </telerik:RadContextMenu>
    </telerik:RadContextMenu.ContextMenu>
</telerik:RadCalendar>
```

### CS

```
private void RadContextMenu_Opened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var calendarButton = (sender as RadContextMenu).GetClickedElement<CalendarButton>();
    if (calendarButton != null)
    {
        var calendarButtonContent = calendarButton.Content as CalendarButtonContent;
        if (calendarButtonContent != null)
        {
            var clickedDate = calendarButtonContent.Date;
            //radCalendar.SelectedDate = calendarButtonContent.Date;
        }
    }
}
```

If i remove the comment in `radCalendar.SelectedDate = calendarButtonContent.Date;` i can select the dates by rightclick, but i need to rightclick again to show the ContextMenu, if i keep it in comment i ContextMenu will show up but i can't change the SelectedDates with rightclick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solved**

instead of using Opened i used Opening and add the handled property

```
private void RadContextMenu_Opening(object sender, Telerik.Windows.RadRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var calendarButton = (sender as RadContextMenu).GetClickedElement<CalendarButton>();
    if (calendarButton != null && (calendarButton.ButtonType == CalendarButtonType.Date || calendarButton.ButtonType == CalendarButtonType.TodayDate))
    {
        var calendarButtonContent = calendarButton.Content as CalendarButtonContent;
        if (calendarButtonContent != null)
        {
            var clickedDate = calendarButtonContent.Date;
            radCalendar.SelectedDate = calendarButtonContent.Date;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```